# Best program for multiplying many multivariable polynomials

Tags: polynomials, matlab, mathematica, maple

I want to make a table with two columns:

The first column will consist of many(possibly hundreds) of polynomials in two variables.

The second column will be a function applied to all of the polynomials. For example, the product of each polynomial with another fixed polynomial.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How do you define each polynomial? Perhaps a vector of its coefficients? Note also that the answer will highly depend on the function you want to apply. Product times another fixed polynomial can be easily done. What other functions do you have in mind?

Comment: @Luis, I want the left column to be x^iy^j, where 1\leq i,j \leq n. Then the right column will be each of these multiplied by x^2y+y^3. I need two indices, but i cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed the multivariable feature of your problem. That makes it trickier

Answer (score 0):

Such a computation in trivial in Maple or Mathematica. Here it is in Maple:

```
n:= 1000:
fixed:= randpoly([x,y]):
polys:= 'randpoly([x,y])' $ n:  polys:= < polys >:
Table:= < polys | expand~(fixed*~polys) >:
```

This takes 0.275 seconds on my computer.  Therefore, you should use some other criterion to decide between the programs.

Comment: Thank you Carl. I am pretty new to this. Can the list of polynomials be entered quickly using indices? For example: polys:= x^iy^j. Or do I have to write them out explicitly?

Comment: Yes, you can use indices. For example seq(seq(x^i*y^j, i= 1..10), j= 1..10)